# Locking mutex twice for asynchronous operation feels wrong

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, mutex

I'm developing an P2P library using C++ and websockets and currently I'm implementing a way to do asynchronous requests towards nodes, given the following class:

```
  class Request {
    private:
      CommandType _command; // The command type.
      std::string _id;      // The request id.
      std::string _nodeId;  // The host node id.
      Message _answer;      // The answer to the request.
      std::mutex _mutex;    // Mutex for waiting for the request.
      bool _isAnswered = false;
      void release() { _mutex.unlock(); };

    public:
      Request(const CommandType& command, const std::string& id, const std::string& nodeId) : _command(command), _id(id), _nodeId(nodeId) {};
      const CommandType command() const { return _command; };
      const std::string_view id() const { return _id; };
      const std::string_view nodeId() const { return _nodeId; };
      const Message& answer() const { return _answer; };
      const bool isAnswered() const { return _isAnswered; };
      void setAnswer(const Message& answer) { _answer = answer; _isAnswered = true; std::cout << "release..." << std::endl; release(); };
      void wait() { if (!_isAnswered) { _mutex.lock(); _mutex.lock(); _mutex.unlock(); } };
  };
```

I have a class called `Manager` that holds a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Request>>` (key is `Request::id()`), and a function (call it `makeRequest`) that creates a Request within the map and return a reference to it.

Before `makeRequest` returns, it will call another function `sendToNode` that will send the request asynchronously (the request string is not stored within the Request class, only the answer), then it returns the reference to the pointer and the function that called `makeRequest` nows calls wait() on the pointer.

After that, the websocket will read asynchronously from the node, call `handleMessage` within `Manager` and parse the ID of the request answer, from there we are able to check if ID exists inside unordered_map, and call `setAnswer` to unlock the double mutex on `wait`

I feel that doing the `wait` function and locking the mutex twice is a horrendous way to solve my issue, is there a different way I can look towards it?

Comment: locking the mutex twice in the same thread has undefined behavior, so you really need to not do that.

Comment: I know that leads to undefined behavior and that is why I'm currently looking for a more elegant solution where the function can wait until the Request was answered asynchronously.

Comment: Are you looking for condition variables?

Comment: It also seems to be a good candidate to use a std::packed_task + its future.  (or use a promise in some way or another). Instead of using your answered flag + holding on to the answer.

Comment: Thank you Pepjin, a std::promise class member and a std::future get function works perfectly, specially now that std::future has a wait_until() function allowing me to handle if the requested node never answers back.

Comment: Good to hear that it works for you now. C++ really has some nice building blocks if you know where to look ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the situation that std::condition_variable is made for. Note that this is how waiting on an std::future as recommended in the comments is typically implemented as well.

Although if you're using C++20 you can do even better and make _isAnswered an std::atomic and use std::atomic::wait(). Based on how you use it, _isAnswered probably ought to be atomic anyway.

An alternative - which is a little more complex to write, but tends to scale better if that's important - is to avoid the future-like interface altogether and use an asynchronous completion callback. This is how asynchronous I/O libraries typically deal with the problem, for good reason.

Note also that std::mutex may be recursive so the double lock might not block, and releasing an std::mutex from another thread is undefined and may do nothing at all, leaving your program deadlocked. Using a binary semaphore instead is a potential alternative, as the semantics you want are well defined for that primitive.